# How to display the ID value in a SUM SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this select query, that summarize columns:

```
SELECT 
SUM (LineTotal),
SUM (VatSum), 
SUM (GTotal)
FROM CSI1
WHERE DocEntry = '100'
```

It shows the expected values correctly, but I need to display the id (DocEntry) value too.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: *"It shows the expected values correctly"* Does it? This would display the column `SUM` 3 times, with 3 separate aliases. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Then you need to GROUP BY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
   DocEntry,
   SUM(LineTotal) AS LineTotal,
   SUM(VatSum) AS VatSum,  
   SUM(GTotal) AS GTotal
FROM (VALUES
   ('100', 1, 1, 1),
   ('100', 1, 1, 1),
   ('200', 1, 1, 1)
) CSI1 (DocEntry, LineTotal, VatSum, GTotal)
WHERE DocEntry = '100'
GROUP BY DocEntry
```

Result:

```
DocEntry LineTotal VatSum GTotal
--------------------------------
100      2         2      2
```